# Model slowing down the game - opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a problem while running my game. The model that I import in the game is quite big, making the fps drop down. That's okay but when I get the camera off from the model, it still stays slow. As other games do, when looking at a high resolution model, the game slows down but when not looking at it, it gets faster. However my game stays slow all the time. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to implement [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28computer_graphics%29), so that you don't render the object (i.e. pass it through the graphics pipeline) when it's not visible.

There are many techniques and algorithms/data structures for this, ranging from manual [view frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum_culling#Viewing_frustum_culling)-testing, to more advanced spatial-querying data structures ([BSPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) and so on).

Comment: Actually the process of throwing away complete objects which are not visible is called culling. Clipping means cutting off the parts of an object which are not visible (geometric algorithm).